# PHP OOP Argument 1 passed to Shop::__construct() must be an instance of

Tags: php, oop

this is my first code & having an error:

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Shop::__construct() must be an instance of Generator, none given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\oop\config.php on line 7 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\oop\shop.class.php on line 8

Line 8:

```
    public function __construct(Generator $generator)
```

My code:

```
class Shop
{
    private $generator;
    private $vates;

    public function __construct(Generator $generator)
    {
        $this->Generator = $generator;
        $this->vates = 'Connected with 250 vates!';
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        if ($this->Generator->isDown())
        {
            echo 'Sorry, the generator is down!';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Sucessfully', $this->vates;
        }
    }
}
```

Config.php:

```
include("system.class.php");
include("shop.class.php");

$generator = new Generator;
$shop = new Shop;
```

System.class

```
class Generator
{
    private $power = false;

    public function powerUp() 
    {
        $this->power = true;
        echo 'You powered up the generator';
    }
    public function shutDown()
    {
        $this->power = false;
        echo 'The generator slowly shutting down...';
    }

    public function isDown()
    {
        return $this->power;
    }
}
```

What have I done wrong?
Thanks ;)

Comment: The structure has many flaws. Did you work with C in the past? You are defining the parameters wrong and instantiate the classes wrong.

Comment: my first code was `echo "Hello World"`

Comment: @Allendar: Huh? Code looks good to me, other than being too tightly coupled. He did make a mistake with `$this->Generator` as it should be `$this->generator`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
include("system.class.php");
include("shop.class.php");

$generator = new Generator;
$shop = new Shop($generator);
```

The construct signature for the shop class is [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) the argument, which means that you can only pass in a Generator object.

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing any arguments to the constructor(s):

```
$generator = new Generator();
$shop = new Shop($generator);
```